# What problems are there sharing folders on Mac Snow Leopard with Windows 8?

Tags: mac, windows-8, file-sharing

I've happily shared folders from my Mac Mini to a Windows 7 PC for years. My Win7 Laptop can still see the shared folders on the Mac.

This week, I upgraded my desktop to Windows 8. Now I can see the Mac itself in the Network but there are no folders in it. My Linux-based NAS and other Windows PCs haven't been affected at all.

What do I need to do to get my network back to it's old state?

Comment: It might just be an authentication thing. You can't browse unless you're authenticated. Did you have anything on win 7 that authenticated your user account against the mac?

Comment: As far as I know, nothing stops you seeing the shares if you aren't authenticated. You just can't open them if you don't have access. As I remember, I authenticated against the Mac directly when I first opened the shares.

Comment: Oh I see, in that case just make sure network discovery is turned on in windows 8. It could be something as simple as that. I don't know if it's in the same place in 8, but in 7 it's in the Network and Sharing Center in Control panel, under Advanced sharing settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that Windows by default didn't give me a chance to enter my username or password. It would attempt to access the Mac as a **guest** if it could.

I had to try to **disable "Guest Account"  in System Preferences** on Snow Leopard.

The next time I tried to connect to the Mac, Explorer prompted me to enter my username and password. After entering valid credentials for the Mac, I could access the directories like normal.

Comment: I managed to understand you. Thanks for the help.